# Why it is problematic to use mutex locks within signal handers?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals, mutex, deadlock

Below is the pseudo code in question:

```
int c;
pthread_mutex_t mtx;


void inc(int count)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
    c += count;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}


int main(void)
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx);
    signal(SIGUSR1, inc);
    signal(SIGUSR2, inc);
    sleep(100000); // Sleep for long enough
    return 0;
}
```

How and why can this code could lead to a deadlock?

Why this is different to the following scenario:

> 1. Thread 1 acquires the mutex.
> 2. Context switch is made and Thread 2 tries to get the lock and put on waiting list.
> 3. Thread 1 finishes and releases the lock.
> 4. Thread 2 wakes up and continues its execution.
> 5. No deadlock.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but the code may invoke UB by missing to initialise `c`.

Comment: @alk,
I'm just fed up with smart-asses flooding SO.

Comment: Then what about doing better ... ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your signal handlers are all going to run in the same thread.  If a second signal arrives while the handler for the first has the mutex locked, your lone thread will again attempt to lock the mutex and deadlock:

```
time    thread 0
----    --------
  0      main:...
  1      main:sleep()
 ...     ...
 100     <<SIGUSR1>>
 101     inc:pthread_mutex_lock()
 102     inc:count += ...
 103     <<SIGUSR2>>
 104     inc:pthread_mutex_lock()  // deadlock
```

Comment: Whether this example is relevant depends on the purpose of the mutex. If the mutex was *only* guarding reentrant calls of the signal handler, then indeed the example applies, but of course that approach is completely broken (because of what you describe), and instead reentrant signal handlers should not be used. On the other hand, if the mutex guards data shared between the signal handler and *other* code, then your example isn't really about a "second signal"; but just generally about "other code".

Comment: If I had a reentrant lock, then I should not have a problem no with the second signal no?

Comment: @Goaler444 No, you will definitely have a problem. Reentrant locks work under the assumption that the locking code is able to finish executing before being called again. Signals non-cooperatively preempt execution at an arbitrary time - potentially while you were in the middle of taking the lock. More or less anything that isn't atomic at the hardware level is in an arbitrary and undefined state when a signal handler is invoked. Here be dragons.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use a mutex in signal handlers because signals are asynchronous. You can not predict their occurring.

In case signal is raised when a thread has already acquired a lock it will result in a deadlock.

The signal handler can not acquire lock until the thread released the lock but the thread can not release the lock, because it can not be resumed without completion of the handler.